# Shell to move file returns Invalid Procedure call or Argument

Tags: vba, excel, csv

Using Windows 10

```
Dim logPathSource As String
Dim logFileSource As String
Dim logPathDest As String
Dim logFileDest As String

logPathSource = "D:\Users\ian_abbott\AppData\Local\Temp\Data Capture Log\"
logFileSource = "moving180827_160818.csv"
logPathDest = "\\ussantapps332\DataCapture\tmp\"
logFileDest = "2018-08-27_16,08,28UKASIABBOTTL10-Ian_Abbott_TESTlogdata.csv"

Shell "cmd /c move """ & logPathSource & logFileSource & """ """ & logPathDest & logFileDest & """", vbHide
```

Putting the PathName for the Shell command into the Immediate Window, I get:

```
cmd /c move "D:\Users\ian_abbott\AppData\Local\Temp\Data Capture Log\moving180827_160818.csv" "\\ussantapps332\DataCapture\tmp\2018-08-27_16,08,28UKASIABBOTTL10-Ian_Abbott_TESTlogdata.csv"
```

If I copy/paste that into Command Prompt, the file is moved and renamed successfully, if I run it from VBA I get

```
Run-time error '5':
Invalid procedure call or argument
```

What am I missing in VBA?

Comment: Maybe try it in [Shell and Wait](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ShellAndWait.aspx) and see which line triggers the error?

Comment: Maybe you need to deal with the double quotes. Try replace """ with "chr(34)" and see if it's working or not.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Shell is supposed to return an integer. Have you tried this instead?

```
dim returnValue as Integer
returnValue = Shell("cmd /c move """ & logPathSource & logFileSource & """ """ & logPathDest & logFileDest & """", vbHide)
```

Comment: I have tried this, i get the same error. The code, exactly as above, has worked for 3+ years on Windows 7 PC's, which is why I suspect it is something to do with Windows 7...